# Can't display a normal image in matplotlib, it keeps displaying with the jet colormap

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, rgb, colormap

I have code that displays the MISER regions of an image:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

imp1 = sys.argv[1]
img1 = cv2.imread(imp1)

mser = cv2.MSER()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
vis = img1.copy()

regions = mser.detect(gray, None)
hulls = [cv2.convexHull(p.reshape(-1, 1, 2)) for p in regions]
cv2.polylines(vis, hulls, 1, (0, 255, 0))

def plot_stuff(img1, img1_name, img2, img2_name):
    fig,axes = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(15,6))


    axes[0].imshow(img1, cmap='Greys_r')
    axes[0].set_title(img1_name)


    axes[1].imshow(img2)
    axes[1].set_title(img2_name)

    fig.suptitle("All Images")
    plt.show()

plot_stuff(img1, 'Original', vis, 'MISER Regions')
```

And it works fine, except it's blue:

[image]
And that's where I got stuck. Because no matter what I do, I can't get it to show the Image as gray, and the MISER lines as green. It keeps returning jet:

[image]

Even when I show just the image, it still returns jet. Why isn't there an RGB colormap? Better yet, why does there have to be a colormap at all, why can't it just show the normal image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You data is stored as 64 bit numpy arrays, from the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html),

> For RGB and RGBA images, matplotlib supports float32 and uint8 data types

You either need it in this format or need to specify a colormap. It seems the other issue is that 'cv2.polylines' returns an images, which means you cannot set the colours of the lines and the background separately. A solution to this is to use a blank transparent image of the same size to draw the mser (MISER!?) curves and then plot them both on the same axis,

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

imp1 = sys.argv[1]
img1 = cv2.imread(imp1)

mser = cv2.MSER()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
vis = np.zeros([img1.shape[0],img1.shape[1],4]) 

regions = mser.detect(gray, None)
hulls = [cv2.convexHull(p.reshape(-1, 1, 2)) for p in regions]
cv2.polylines(vis, hulls, 1, (0, 255, 0))
vis = np.array(vis, dtype=np.uint8)

#Copy green channel data to (alpha) transparent channel
vis[:,:,3] = vis[:,:,1]

def plot_stuff(img1, img1_name, img2, img2_name):
    fig,axes = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(15,6))

    print(img1.shape)
    axes[0].imshow(np.sum(img1,2), cmap='Greys_r')
    axes[0].set_title(img1_name)

    axes[1].imshow(np.sum(img1,2), cmap='Greys_r')
    axes[1].imshow(img2)
    axes[1].set_title(img2_name)

    fig.suptitle("All Images")
    plt.show()

plot_stuff(img1, 'Original', vis, 'MISER Regions')
```

which for me returns,
[image]

using matplotlib.**version** 1.4.3' and cv2.**version**'$Rev: 4557 $'

Answer (score 0):

The imshow docs says that cmap is ignored when image has RGB information.

You can consider creating a gray level image

```
newimg = numpy.sum(img, 2)
```

Then

```
ax.imshow(newimg, cmap='gray')
```

Comment: No, it's still colormaped.

Comment: Wait, and I got a type error: `TypeError: Layout of the output array img is incompatible with cv::Mat (step[ndims-1] != elemsize or step[1] != elemsize*nchannels)`

Comment: Maybe it's the CV datatype. You can try casting the img by `newimg = np.array(img)`

Comment: Now both of them are colormaped. Why can't it just show the image?

Comment: Did you use both the 'np.array' and the 'np.sum'?

Comment: Yes: `newimg = np.array(img1), newimg2 = np.sum(newimg, 2)`

Comment: And then: `plot_stuff(newimg2, 'Original', vis, 'MISER Regions')`

Comment: I already can make the *original* image grey, I wanted the output image grey, but the MISER reasons still green. If I set axes[1].imshow(img2, cmap='Greys_r'), then the entire image is grey: http://i.imgur.com/mXZ7bRx.png and I can't see the lines.

Comment: Correction: I meant `axes[1].imshow(img2, cmap='Greys_r')`